# mysql timestamp query, select all but first records for a given minute

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a table that stores data about snapshots my IP cameras take.  Generally, the cameras take multiple snapshots per minute, although one of my cameras is configured to take just one snapshot per minute.

I purge items from the table (and disk), but retain according to the following rules:

1. For the first 7 days, all images are kept
2. Anything over 7 days old, just keep the first snapshot per hour of the day
3. Anything over 4 weeks, just keep the first snapshot in the 06th, 12th and 18th hour of the day
4. Anything over 3 months old, just keep the first snapshot in the 12th hour of the day.

The following is my current query, which works OK, except it keeps all snapshots taken during the first minute of any hour.

```
SELECT camera_id,
       timestamp,
       frame,
       filename
FROM snapshot_frame
WHERE ((timestamp < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
        AND minute(timestamp) != 0)
       OR (timestamp < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
           AND (hour(timestamp) NOT IN (6,
                                        12,
                                        18)
                OR minute(timestamp) != 0))
       OR (timestamp < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
           AND (hour(timestamp) != 12
                OR minute(timestamp) != 0)))
```

How can I retain just the first snapshot per minute for any timestamp over 7 days old in accordance with the above rules?

In case it helps, the table/index structure:

```
mysql> describe snapshot_frame;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| camera_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| frame     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| filename  | varchar(100) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> show index from snapshot_frame;
+----------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| snapshot_frame |          0 | filename        |            1 | filename    | A         |     3052545 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| snapshot_frame |          1 | idx_time_camera |            1 | timestamp   | A         |     3052545 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| snapshot_frame |          1 | idx_time_camera |            2 | camera_id   | A         |     3052545 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.42 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from snapshot_frame;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  3030214 |
+----------+
1 row in set (18.47 sec)
```

Update: So I have managed to create a query that provides all of the snapshots that I want to keep, according to my rules:

```
SELECT camera_id,
       TIMESTAMP,
       frame,
       filename
FROM snapshot_frame
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= subdate(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
UNION
  (SELECT camera_id,
          TIMESTAMP,
          frame,
          filename
   FROM snapshot_frame
   WHERE TIMESTAMP < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
     AND TIMESTAMP >= subdate(now(), INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
     AND minute(TIMESTAMP) = 0
   GROUP BY camera_id,
            year(TIMESTAMP),
            month(TIMESTAMP),
            date(TIMESTAMP),
            hour(TIMESTAMP),
            minute(TIMESTAMP))
UNION
  (SELECT camera_id,
          TIMESTAMP,
          frame,
          filename
   FROM snapshot_frame
   WHERE TIMESTAMP < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
     AND TIMESTAMP >= subdate(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
     AND hour(TIMESTAMP) IN (6,
                             12,
                             18)
     AND minute(TIMESTAMP) = 0
   GROUP BY camera_id,
            year(TIMESTAMP),
            month(TIMESTAMP),
            date(TIMESTAMP),
            hour(TIMESTAMP),
            minute(TIMESTAMP))
UNION
  (SELECT camera_id,
          TIMESTAMP,
          frame,
          filename
   FROM snapshot_frame
   WHERE TIMESTAMP < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
     AND hour(TIMESTAMP) = 12
     AND minute(TIMESTAMP) = 0
   GROUP BY camera_id,
            year(TIMESTAMP),
            month(TIMESTAMP),
            date(TIMESTAMP),
            hour(TIMESTAMP),
            minute(TIMESTAMP))
```

I am just trying to work out how to reverse that now, so I return a result set that contains all rows from `snapshot_frame` that aren't in the above query.

Any pointers?

Comment: I have a solution, though not one I am ecstatic about.  Basically, I use the above query to create a temporary table of the rows that I wish to keep and then I run a query across all snapshots to determine which ones don't exist in the temporary table.  I will update my original question, since I can't answer my own question.

Comment: Oh boy. That's a lot of stuff.

Comment: You mean, as in a large query?  Or lots of information?  Either way, I will take any advice on how to be more efficient ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I am now using is to populate a temporary table with the rows that I wish to keep:

```
CREATE
TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS retain_frames (INDEX idx_time_camera (timestamp, camera_id))AS
SELECT camera_id,
       timestamp,
       frame,
       filename
FROM (
        (SELECT camera_id,
                timestamp,
                frame,
                filename
         FROM snapshot_frame a
         WHERE timestamp >= subdate(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
      UNION
        (SELECT camera_id,
                timestamp,
                frame,
                filename
         FROM snapshot_frame b
         WHERE timestamp < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
           AND timestamp >= subdate(now(), INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
           AND minute(timestamp) = 0
         GROUP BY camera_id,
                  date(timestamp),
                  hour(timestamp),
                  minute(timestamp))
      UNION
        (SELECT camera_id,
                timestamp,
                frame,
                filename
         FROM snapshot_frame c
         WHERE timestamp < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 4 WEEK)
           AND timestamp >= subdate(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
           AND hour(timestamp) IN (6,
                                   12,
                                   18)
           AND minute(timestamp) = 0
         GROUP BY camera_id,
                  date(timestamp),
                  hour(timestamp),
                  minute(timestamp))
      UNION
        (SELECT camera_id,
                timestamp,
                frame,
                filename
         FROM snapshot_frame d
         WHERE timestamp < subdate(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
           AND hour(timestamp) = 12
           AND minute(timestamp) = 0
         GROUP BY camera_id,
                  date(timestamp),
                  hour(timestamp),
                  minute(timestamp))) e
```

and then select the stale snapshots using the following query:

```
SELECT camera_id,
       timestamp,
       frame,
       filename
FROM snapshot_frame a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT camera_id,
            timestamp,
            frame,
            filename
     FROM retain_frames b
     WHERE a.camera_id = b.camera_id
       AND a.timestamp = b.timestamp
       AND a.frame = b.frame)
```

The only issue is that the creation of the temporary table takes about 2 minutes and seems to lock the DB up causing sporadic `OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')` being thrown in my python code by another thread that is attempting to insert into that same table.

Comment: You've accepted this so there's unlikely to be any follow-up

Comment: I just unaccepted, in case anyone has anything that they might like to add.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, aside from GROUP BY being pointless, it is highly likely that it is returning the results you expect. At its core, your problem is of the GROUPWISE-MAX variety. This is something of a FAQ, so much so that the manual devotes an entire page to it.